# What is the keyboard shortcut to switch between terminal tabs?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut to switch between terminal tabs? `Ctrl+PgDn/PgUp` doesn't work.

Comment: In the Pantheon Terminal you can move between terminal tabs with Ctrl+Shift+← and Ctrl+Shift+→ respectively.

Comment: @lemonslice this is the actual answer to the question - can you please post it as such?

Answer (score 3):

`Alt + <1-9>` Jumps to first-ninth tab.

Comment: doesn't work (could it be because of locale?)